# using CString with boost string algorithms - reduce to one typedef?

Tags: c++, boost, range, cstring

I need to write some code for a MFC project, but I don't know how to get required code to work when using MFC.

I prototyped my function first just using the STL types, and boost.

**STL Prototype**

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/classification.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/find.hpp>

void ProtoTest()
{
    std::string sText("123Hello4");
    boost::iterator_range<std::string::iterator> nc_result = find_token(sText, boost::algorithm::is_alpha(), boost::algorithm ::token_compress_on);
}
```

*Result = "Hello"*

I eventually managed to get it working with MFC, however I had to supply two typedefs.  I would like to do it in one, however there isn't much documentation on using the MFC port provided in boost.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <boost\range\atl.hpp>

void Test()
{
    typedef boost::range_iterator<CString>::type CString_it;
    typedef boost::iterator_range<CString_it> CString_range;
    CString strText("123Hello4");
    CString_range r;
    r = find_token(text, boost::algorithm::is_alpha(), boost::algorithm ::token_compress_on);
}
```

Again *Result = "Hello"*

Is there a single typedef I can use to hold the result of find_token, rather than needing two typdefs to achieve it.

Comment: The question is what single typedef should be supplied to hold the answer to find_token, when using MFC strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just combine them

```
typedef boost::iterator_range<boost::range_iterator<CString>::type> CString_range;
```

But I don't know if that is an advantage.

Comment: Nor am I, however I still think it is an improvement.  I think I will probably go with your answer.  I'll just leave it for a little while longer.

Thanks Bo